# Pycharm converts mail of git authors to lowercase

Tags: git, pycharm

I have an issue in Pycharm IDE with git. I wanted to view git log via Pycharm (menu => Git/Show Git Log) and then cherry-pick some comments between branches. What I found, is that author mails, which should contain uppercase characters for different authors, were in lowercase. This causes me issues because it incorrectly identifies authors. Now when I check git log in this repository in bash, author mails for given commits are displayed correctly with uppercase characters, so it appears to be IDE related issue.

I am using 2023.1.4 Community edition Pycharm with git 2.34.1

I tried searching relevant git settings in Pycharm IDE or looking for similar issues on google, but found nothing relevant.

Comment: If this involves the local-part (the part before the `@` sign), then this is a bug, because the standard is very clear that that portion is case-sensitive and always has been.  The domain is not case sensitive.  You would report the bug in the normal way.

Comment: Yes, it is the part before @ sign. Thanks, then I will report it as a bug.